# Feeds: import content from CSV url list with QueryPath or alternative to find image or body in external HTML

Tags: 9, feeds

The situation:

Partner provides us with relatively simple CSV that only has title and url to article with permission to use images or body of that article, but... "not a tech person, no idea how to export everything".

Task:

Import some divs/imgs from external website with Feeds module just using that CSV url list.

I'm quite familiar with Feeds, at least when all data is provided within CSV/XML, with img URLs available. But here I'm a bit lost how to achieve that with some HTML lookup.

UPDATE:

The CSV I have is something like that:

```
"Article 1 title", "https://example.com/article-1"
"Article 2 title", "https://example.com/article-2"
```

HTML at target:

```
<article class="article">
  <img class="article-image" src="...">
  <div class="body">...</div>
</article>
```

What I want to achieve is that Feeds would create a node with fields:

```
1. Title
2. Article image (image from class "article-image")
3. Article body (html inside class "body")
```

I hope that clarifies the situation.

I guess what @Patrick Kenny suggested is the way to go, but maybe there are some other ideas.

Comment: I do not fully understand this question. It needs more detail, perhaps examples, and anything else that may explain it to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Requirements

- There is a CSV file with a list of URLs.
- You need to get image files used in `<img>` tags on that list of URLs.

So you need to parse the URLs listed in the CSV file.  You will need to extend Feeds to do this with custom code.

However, you can get a head start by using the [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) module, which gives you a way to process the CSV columns with your custom code.

The way to implement this:

1. Create your own Feeds Tamper plugin.
2. Write custom code to extract the images you need from a given URL. (This is a Stack Overflow question and off topic for this site.)
3. On the settings page for your feed, add your custom tamper plugin.
4. Import the feed.